# Vim line wrap: how to insert backslash '\' automatically when wrapping a line?

Tags: vim, indentation

Suppose I `:set tw=5`, when wrapping the following 'long' line:

```
a = b + c
```

It becomes:

```
a = b
+ c
```

Yet I want it to be:

```
a = b \
+ c
```

Or even better if smart indent inserted before next line, like this:

```
a = b \
  + c
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is `:h formatexpr`.

You'll want to define a expression that checks what mode you are in `mode() ==# 'i'` and then perform the changes you wish to have happen. Returning non-zero will use the default expr.

E.g.

```
set formatexpr=FormatFoo()
function! FormatFoo()
  if mode() ==# 'i'
    echom "insertmode line wrap"
    return 1
  else
    echom "normalmode line wrap"
    return 1
  endif
endfunction
```